# How to expose state to localStorage with polymer 3 PWA starter template

Tags: typescript, polymer, local-storage, web-component, progressive-web-apps

I am using the Polymer 3 PWA starter package template taken from here:
https://github.com/Polymer/pwa-starter-kit/tree/template-typescript

I now want to put the state to localStorage as described in the documentation. So I am adding localstorage.ts file

```
export const saveState = (state) => {
    let stringifiedState = JSON.stringify(state);
    localStorage.setItem('__wtt_store__', stringifiedState);
  }

export const loadState = () => {
    try {
        let json = localStorage.getItem('__wtt_store__') || '{}';
        let state = JSON.parse(json);
        console.log("local storage state:"+state.counter.clicks);

        if (state) {
        return state;
        } else {
        return undefined;  // To use the defaults in the reducers
        }
    } catch { 
        console.log("local storage error");
        return undefined;
    }
  }
```

and changed the store.ts file from the template:

```
export const store = createStore(
  state => state as Reducer<RootState, RootAction>,
  loadState(),  // --------- LINE ADDED -----------------
  devCompose(
    lazyReducerEnhancer(combineReducers),
    applyMiddleware(thunk as ThunkMiddleware<RootState, RootAction>))
);

// Initially loaded reducers.
store.addReducers({
  app
});

// ---------  ADDED -----------------
store.subscribe(() => {
  saveState(store.getState());
});
```

The console log shows me that state is written to localStorage and loaded once browser is refreshed. But inital data values of the components are back to initial values after reload, not to the values of the saved localStorage?

What needs to be added that the data from localStorage are used during initialization in the web component? I am just trying to save the "counter" example to localStorage from the PWA template my-view2.ts. But with no success.

What needs to be done to write the counter data from my-view2.ts of the PWA template to localStorage and to reload to state back afterwards? My solutions is not working according to the standard procedure from the manual.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution.

Root-cause:
The `saveState(store.getState());`is called everytime a store update has been received. In the app start ts template, there is only the reducer for the app loaded. The reducer for the counter element is not loaded during initialization of the app and lazy load. Therefore any stored value in the localStore from the last session is now overwritten by the new saveState function with only the app store data. In this case overwriting the previous saved counter data with empty data. This results in empty data once the counter element is loaded and the reducer is initialized.

Solution:
During initial load of the localStore I save the original full localState from last session in a variable like this:

```
export let initialLocalState:any={};
export const loadState = () => {
    try {
        let json = localStorage.getItem('__wtt_store__') || '{}';
        let state = JSON.parse(json);
        //console.log("load local app storage state:"+state.counter.clicks);

        if (state) {
            initialLocalState=state;
            //console.log("Original: "+JSON.stringify(initialLocalState))
            return state;
        } else {
            return undefined;  // To use the defaults in the reducers
        }
    } catch { 
        console.log("local storage error");
        return undefined;
    }
  }
```

Now, to avoid overwriting the full data with a early call of saveState where not all data might be initialized, I merge the full content back into the storage before saving:

```
export const saveState = (state) => {
    if (state==null) return;

    //ensure that we merge it with the full initial local state received during app start and store creation
    //fill up the last session state with lazy new states
    var merged = Object.assign({}, initialLocalState, state);

    let stringifiedState = JSON.stringify(merged);
    //console.log("Saving: "+stringifiedState);
    localStorage.setItem('__wtt_store__', stringifiedState);
  }
```

Finally, I added an action to the counter.ts web component to fetch the initial data from the localStorage

```
// load initial data from localStore, if available
store.dispatch(loadfavorite());
```

This solutions helps me to keep to proposed structure of the PWA starter kit components with lazy loading of the components and reducers and provides a way to keep the localStorage data from the last session fully available.